# IF condition from excel to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm confused on how to pass this problem from excel to VBA:

In excel:

Theoric:

```
=IF(cond1, IF(cond2, statement1,statement2),IF(cond2,statement3,statement4))
```

Actual excel cells:

```
=IF($B$2="USD",IF($B$170="USD",B173,B173/B$1),IF($B$170="USD",B173*B$1,B173))
```

In VBA:

```
If cond1 Then
If cond2 Then
Statement1
Else
Statement2
End if
Elseif cond2 Then
statement3
Else
statement4
End if
```

Would it be ok ?

Comment: Do you want to create a VBA function to use in the cell? for example your new cell formula would then read `=Myfunction(B2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this as an alternative?

```
Select Case CStr(Range("B2").text = "USD") & CStr(Range("B170").text = "USD")
Case Is = "TrueFalse"
    Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value / Range("B1").Value
Case Is = "FalseTrue"
    Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value * Range("B1").Value
Case Else
    Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value
End Select
```

Just been playing around with this a bit more, you can mathematically get it smaller by using the boolean as a value in your calculation, it gets down to just 2 lines of code, set the value for an exception then overwrite it if it meets the criteria.

We use the maths here that X * Y = X / (1/Y)

By knowing this we can use the boolean as 1 or 0 and manipulate a formula that way.

Here is what I came up with:

```
Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value
If CLng(Range("B2").Text = "USD") + CLng(Range("B170").Text = "USD") = -1 Then Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value * (((CLng(Range("B2").Text = "USD") * -1) / Range("B1").Value) + ((CLng(Range("B170").Text = "USD") * -1) * Range("B1").Value))
```

It is much harder to read and maintain than my original suggestion though :).

Comment: Cool ! nice approach

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you are asking:

```
If Range("B2") = "USD" Then
    If Range("B170") = "USD" Then
        Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value
    Else
        Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value / Range("B1").Value
    End If
Else
    If Range("B170") = "USD" Then
        Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value * Range("B1").Value
    Else
        Range("A1").Value = Range("B173").Value
    End If
End If
```

This assumes that you want the value in A1.

Also formatting the code as above allows it to be easier read.